# Rearrange the columns of a pandas DataFrame based on row number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

There is a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'a':[3,0,2,1],'b':[4,3,2,1],'c':[3,2,1,0],'d':[4,3,2,0]})
print(df)
>>> df
   a  b  c  d
0  3  4  3  4
1  0  3  2  3
2  2  2  1  2
3  1  1  0  0
```

How to rearrange(sort?) entire df based on the distribution of numbers in the cells in each column? for example, the content of a column is [3,2,1], then it should be arranged before other columns that elements is [3,2,0]. When comparing two columns, the numbers in each row are compared in sequence. If the first row is the same, the next row is compared.

The desired results are as follows:

```
>>> dd
   b  d  c  a
0  4  4  3  3
1  3  3  2  0
2  2  2  1  2
3  1  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an efficient solution, don't reinvent the wheel, use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) directly:

```
out = df.sort_values(by=list(df.index), axis=1, ascending=False)
```

Or eventually [`numpy.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html):

```
out = df.iloc[:, np.lexsort(-df[::-1].to_numpy())]
```

Output:

```
   b  d  c  a
0  4  4  3  3
1  3  3  2  0
2  2  2  1  2
3  1  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 3):

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [3, 0, 2, 1], 'b': [4, 3, 2, 1], 'c': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'd': [4, 3, 2, 0]})

def custom_sort(col):
    return tuple(col.values)

sorted_columns = sorted(df.columns, key=lambda col: custom_sort(df[col]), reverse=True)
df_sorted = df[sorted_columns]
print(df_sorted)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: IMO, that's not a good approach, converting to tuple and using python's `sorted` is inefficient when you can do it directly in pure pandas/numpy.

Answer (score 0):

I also found a solution by weighting the elements of each column.

```
>>> df
   a  b  c  d
0  3  4  3  4
1  0  3  2  3
2  2  2  1  2
3  1  1  0  0
df[df.apply(lambda x:sum(x * pow(10, np.arange(len(x))[::-1]))).sort_values(ascending=False).index]
   b  d  c  a
0  4  4  3  3
1  3  3  2  0
2  2  2  1  2
3  1  0  0  1
```